# how to get custom attribute select option values from custom table in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.3.5-p1, attribute-options

I want to get attribute option value which is created from admin side in using custom field in magento 2.3.5

please anyone can have knowlwdge about it then please share with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want to get product attribute with its option?

Comment: product attribute with options that already created with options from dtatabse table